# How do I track users in my database without affecting response times?

Tags: design-patterns, redis, fastapi

I'm designing a big (for me) backend API with users and I want to try when users were last seen, and what IPs they are seen with (all of them).

The usual way I do this is with a simple middleware - the middleware checks if they are authenticated. If they are, it simply updates a database entry with the current time. Then the middleware just continues to the requested function.

However, I'm dealing with more data and I want this to be done as smoothly as possible - I want the middleware to finish ASAP with no blocking database operations. I have some ideas:

1. I use FastAPI's background tasks to do this. I don't know how much overhead they induce, and given that they would be ran on EVERY route, this seems inefficient to be creating a background task just to update a timestamp in a database. If I want this to scale, I'd have to use `celery` or something, which might be *even slower*.
2. Redis. This seems most likely; I could simply store the timestamp and IP keyed by their address. On an interval (15-60s), I could have the API look at all the entries and update the database accordingly. This should make the requests as fast they could be, no overhead, very scalable, and the true disk database would be updated in a period that is roughly 'real time'. I like this solution, but I worry it may be classified as premature optimization.

To be clear, the requirements I'm looking for are

- Scalable. This has to work when 10,000 users are hitting my API simultaneously, otherwise I have to drop the feature.
- Responsive - The design is probably going to use a middleware of sorts, and this has to exit instantly. I cannot have a working waiting on something like a DB transaction to go through. The response time **must** not be hindered by this feature.
- Relatively Real-time - The database has to have these IPs and User IDs usable in less than 60 seconds. I could get fleixble with this requirement, but I'd rather not be waiting too long before things can be queried.

Comment: You're talking about premature optimization, then about "10000 users simultaneously" - considering there is no such as "simultaneously" when it comes to user traffic (i.e. are we talking 10k req/s, or 10k active users within an hour?). Set an actual goal (if you already have an API running that does this, you should have an idea of the most req/s you're currently seeing), then see if the naive way works good enough. Then start optimizing - talking about optimization at all without knowing what is "good enough" is going to be hard; start with the easy solution and see if it's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer may not be the definitive answer, but here are my two cents:

#### PREMISE

- 10k users are quite a lot, but it mostly depends on what you do with those 10k requests. Your app, with or without this feature, may not be capable of handling such traffic. Hence it should be horizontally scalable
- You'll need to accept some sort of trade-off between features and scalability. The beauty of horizontal scalability, is that if you need more resources, you just add horizontally a server/service.
- It's difficoult that have near real-time if you're doing some heavy work. I'm not sure what does the app do, but many factor account for the waiting time, some of which (if not most) are out of your control.

#### ACTUAL ANSWER

That being said, I guess that the middleware is the best option. You could get the data (IP, user id, etc.) and perform an `async` call to the database for updating the data. Without awaiting the response from the database, let the request be processed and only when it's done, you `await` for the response. This will impact relatively the timing, but as mentioned above, there have to be some trade-offs. Even with an external system, you'll have to get the user information along with the IP (and something else?) and then perform a call and wait for it.

#### EXAMPLE IDEA

You can do something like

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends
# other imports

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def record_user_activity(request: Request, user = Depends(get_user), call_next):
    # get user IP and other data
    # do here the call for inserting the data into the db
    # DO NOT AWAIT IT
    response = await call_next(request)
    # NOW AWAIT THE CALL TO THE DB TO MAKE SURE IT HAS FINISHED CORRECTLY
    return response
```

Comment: I talked to someone just before reading this and yep, that's pretty much the conclusion we arrived at, but you've even provided some code! While I wanted to use Redis with a reasonably good implementation, it seems this would be smarter...

Comment: Well, you can use redis, though I'm not aware of how you would track the users, so it's difficoult to say. From my experience, it is usually in the `user` record, but you may use a different approach, e.g. an append only table for recording all accesses (this may blow in disk consumption)